# It seems critical updating from local.xml in magento

Tags: magento

How can it be solved?I want to 'My Cart' link not in top menu, rather in other place. So I deleted  from checkout.xml:

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
        <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Then add new reference:

```
<reference name="top.mybasket">
    <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
        <action method="addCartLink"></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

From page.xml i add this:

```
    <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
// other blocks
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.mybasket" as="my_basket_count"/>
</block>
```

Next i add in header.phtml by:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my_basket_count') ?>
```

All works fine.
**My question is how this whole process can be done in local.xml?** I tried but it looks critical!

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question.But this link might help you http://classyllama.com/development/magento-development/the-better-way-to-modify-magento-layout/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I already read the link but there is no description about creating and modifying it from **local.xml** file!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the content of local.xml you need if i understand correctly your requirements:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
 <default>
  <reference name="top.links">
   <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>
  </reference>
  <reference name="root">
   <reference name="header">
    <block type="page/template_links" name="top.mybasket" as="my_basket_count"/>
   </reference>
  </reference>
  <reference name="top.mybasket">
   <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
    <action method="addCartLink"></action>
   </block>
  </reference>
 </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I came to know the new way of adding block,referencing and then updating from **layout.xml** very nice.    In this i want to keep **Checkout** link so i add this <reference name="top.links">
      <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
                <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
            </block>
  </reference>       Is this way right!

Comment: The comment above is **not working** : `<reference name="top.links"> <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link"> <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action> </block> </reference>` How can i delete **My Cart** link from local.xml (**throwing question again**)

Comment: Doesn't this bit work for you?

<reference name="top.links">
 <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>
</reference>

Comment: Still trying! But No luck. So i have deleted My Cart link from top.links reference and added **in your way**